# Returning Multiple Objects in Shiny

Tags: r, shiny, shiny-server, quantitative-finance, shiny-reactivity

Hello fellow R users I am relatively new to shiny , I am trying to develop a basic app that takes 4 stocks and print  the optimal portfolio weights and plots the  chart those weights . However my app is only printing  the  optimal portfolio weights and not the plot of the charted weights . 
Here is my code :

```
library(shiny)
library(PortfolioAnalytics)
library(quantmod)
library(PerformanceAnaltics)

server = function(input, output, session) {
  dsf=reactive({
    ticker<-c(input$stock1, input$stock2, input$stock3, input$stock4)
    portfolioPrice <- NULL
    for(ticker in ticker) {
      portfolioPrice <- cbind(portfolioPrice,
                              getSymbols.yahoo(ticker,  periodicity = 'daily', auto.assign=FALSE)[,6])
    }
    poty=na.omit(ROC(portfolioPrice))

    portf <- portfolio.spec(colnames(poty))
    portf <- add.constraint(portf, type="weight_sum", min_sum=.99, max_sum=1.01)
    portf <- add.constraint(portf, type="box", min=.02, max=.60) 
    portf<-add.constraint(portf,type="transation_cost", ptc=.001)
    portf <- add.objective(portfolio = portf, type="return", name="mean")
    portf <- add.objective(portfolio = portf, type="risk", name="StdDev")


    optPort <- optimize.portfolio(poty, portf, optimize_method = "random", trace=TRUE)
    ws=extractWeights(optPort)


    silf=chart.Weights(optPort)

    return(list(silf, ws))



  })



  output$wad<-renderPrint({
    dsf()
  })

  output$wadS<-renderPlot({
    dsf()
  })





} # the server

ui = basicPage(
  textInput("stock1", "stock1"),
  textInput("stock2", "stock2"),
  textInput("stock3", "stock3"),
  textInput("stock4", "stock4"),


  verbatimTextOutput("wad"),
  plotOutput("wadS")



) # the user interface

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server) # perform app launch
```

Here is a picture of the app

[image]

As you can see the app takes  the 4 stocks and returns the optimal portfolio weights however it is supposed to not only print  the optimal weights but it is also supposed plot the chart of the weights  .

like this :

[image]

How do I get my app to return the printed weights and return my plot of the charted weights , thank you very much for your help

Comment: Hey guys I really need help here this is really important to me . does anyone need me to clarify the question or anything .

Comment: try sthg like: `output$wadS<-renderPlot({dsf()$silf})`. You might get more responds if your make your code reproducible and show that you read more tutorials. All the best!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you are returning two different objects in a list within the `dsf` reactive object, but you are specifying to render both text and a plot out of that list, which doesn't make a sense.

The best route is to break up your reactive objects into separate reactive objects. Try the following. Here I've set it up so that `dsf()` houses the data, and two separate reactive objects, `ws` for the print and `silf` for the plot:

```
library(shiny)
library(PortfolioAnalytics)
library(quantmod)
library(PerformanceAnaltics)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  dsf <- reactive({
    ticker<-c(input$stock1, input$stock2, input$stock3, input$stock4)
    portfolioPrice <- NULL
    for(ticker in ticker) {
      portfolioPrice <- cbind(portfolioPrice,
                              getSymbols.yahoo(ticker,  periodicity = 'daily', auto.assign=FALSE)[,6])
    }
    poty=na.omit(ROC(portfolioPrice))

    portf <- portfolio.spec(colnames(poty))
    portf <- add.constraint(portf, type="weight_sum", min_sum=.99, max_sum=1.01)
    portf <- add.constraint(portf, type="box", min=.02, max=.60) 
    portf<-add.constraint(portf,type="transation_cost", ptc=.001)
    portf <- add.objective(portfolio = portf, type="return", name="mean")
    portf <- add.objective(portfolio = portf, type="risk", name="StdDev")


    optimize.portfolio(poty, portf, optimize_method = "random", trace=TRUE)
  })

  ws <- reactive({
    extractWeights(dsf())
  })


  silf <- reactive({
    chart.Weights(dsf())
  })

  output$wad<-renderPrint({
    ws()
  })

  output$wadS<-renderPlot({
    silf()
  })

  } # the server

ui = basicPage(
  textInput("stock1", "stock1"),
  textInput("stock2", "stock2"),
  textInput("stock3", "stock3"),
  textInput("stock4", "stock4"),


  verbatimTextOutput("wad"),
  plotOutput("wadS")

) # the user interface

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server) # perform app launch
```